# Python, all combinations of element addition between two lists, with constraint

Tags: python, list, loops, recursion, python-itertools

I have two lists:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [0.5, 1]
```

The task is to create all possible combinations from the original list by adding the variables from the second list to its elements:

```
list1 = [1+0.5, 2, 3]
list2 = [1, 2+0.5, 3]
list3 = [1, 2, 3+0.5]
list4 = [1+0.5, 2+0.5, 3]
list5 = [1, 2+0.5, 3+0.5]
list6 = [1+0.5, 2, 3+0.5]
list7 = [1+0.5, 2+0.5, 3+0.5]

list8 = [1+1, 2, 3]
list9 = [1,2+1,3]
list10 = [1,2,3+1]
list 11 = [1+1,2+1,3]
...
list = [1+0.5, 2+1, 3]
list = [1+0.5, 2, 3+1]
...
```

Adding complexity to the problem, I'd like to do the above but with a constraint: sum of all elements in new list should be less than 8, for example.

Is there a nice way to do this? Possibly recursively given my initial list would have around 30 elements and my second list around 5?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a combinatoric nightmare. You've got 5 choose 1-5 groups of lists, each of which must select 30 choose 1-30 indices to change, with each chosen index being adjusted by one of 1-5 different values (depending on the number of values chosen for that list group). The worst group, with 30 choose 15 indices to adjust, with five values to choose from for each index, by itself, would involve over 4.7 quintillion lists. It can't be done.

Comment: Is there a way to prune possible list options using the constraint at hand?

Comment: Without a much more detailed limitation, no. Any limit that doesn't effectively allow you to prune the vast majority of options up front is a non-starter.

Comment: Understood, and thank you. Any chance you could show me how you'd do it for the example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion with generator, providing a condition to check the running value of the accumulated sum:

Solution with demo string representation:

```
def pairs(a, b, _l, _c = []):
  if len(_c) == _l:
    yield _c
  else:
     if a:
       for i in b:
         yield from pairs(a[1:], b, _l, _c=_c+[f'{a[0]}+{i}'])
         yield from pairs(a[1:], b, _l, _c= _c+[a[0]])

print(list(pairs([1, 2, 3], [0.5, 1], 3)))
```

Output:

```
[['1+0.5', '2+0.5', '3+0.5'], ['1+0.5', '2+0.5', 3], ['1+0.5', '2+0.5', '3+1'], ['1+0.5', '2+0.5', 3], ['1+0.5', 2, '3+0.5'], ['1+0.5', 2, 3], ['1+0.5', 2, '3+1'], ['1+0.5', 2, 3], ['1+0.5', '2+1', '3+0.5'], ['1+0.5', '2+1', 3], ['1+0.5', '2+1', '3+1'], ['1+0.5', '2+1', 3], ['1+0.5', 2, '3+0.5'], ['1+0.5', 2, 3], ['1+0.5', 2, '3+1'], ['1+0.5', 2, 3], [1, '2+0.5', '3+0.5'], [1, '2+0.5', 3], [1, '2+0.5', '3+1'], [1, '2+0.5', 3], [1, 2, '3+0.5'], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, '3+1'], [1, 2, 3], [1, '2+1', '3+0.5'], [1, '2+1', 3], [1, '2+1', '3+1'], [1, '2+1', 3], [1, 2, '3+0.5'], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, '3+1'], [1, 2, 3], ['1+1', '2+0.5', '3+0.5'], ['1+1', '2+0.5', 3], ['1+1', '2+0.5', '3+1'], ['1+1', '2+0.5', 3], ['1+1', 2, '3+0.5'], ['1+1', 2, 3], ['1+1', 2, '3+1'], ['1+1', 2, 3], ['1+1', '2+1', '3+0.5'], ['1+1', '2+1', 3], ['1+1', '2+1', '3+1'], ['1+1', '2+1', 3], ['1+1', 2, '3+0.5'], ['1+1', 2, 3], ['1+1', 2, '3+1'], ['1+1', 2, 3], [1, '2+0.5', '3+0.5'], [1, '2+0.5', 3], [1, '2+0.5', '3+1'], [1, '2+0.5', 3], [1, 2, '3+0.5'], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, '3+1'], [1, 2, 3], [1, '2+1', '3+0.5'], [1, '2+1', 3], [1, '2+1', '3+1'], [1, '2+1', 3], [1, 2, '3+0.5'], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, '3+1'], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Solution with addition and pruning:

```
def pairs(a, b, _l, _c = [], _sum=0):
  if len(_c) == _l:
    yield _c
  else:
    if a:
      for i in b:
        if a[0]+i+_sum < 8:
          yield from pairs(a[1:], b, _l, _c=_c+[a[0]+i], _sum=_sum+a[0]+i)
        if a[0]+_sum < 8:
          yield from pairs(a[1:], b, _l, _c= _c+[a[0]], _sum=_sum+a[0])

print(list(pairs([1, 2, 3], [0.5, 1], 3, _sum=0)))
```

Output:

```
[[1.5, 2.5, 3.5], [1.5, 2.5, 3], [1.5, 2.5, 3], [1.5, 2, 3.5], [1.5, 2, 3], [1.5, 2, 4], [1.5, 2, 3], [1.5, 3, 3], [1.5, 3, 3], [1.5, 2, 3.5], [1.5, 2, 3], [1.5, 2, 4], [1.5, 2, 3], [1, 2.5, 3.5], [1, 2.5, 3], [1, 2.5, 4], [1, 2.5, 3], [1, 2, 3.5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3.5], [1, 3, 3], [1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3.5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 2.5, 3], [2, 2.5, 3], [2, 2, 3.5], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3.5], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2.5, 3.5], [1, 2.5, 3], [1, 2.5, 4], [1, 2.5, 3], [1, 2, 3.5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3.5], [1, 3, 3], [1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3.5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Edit: specifying lower bound:

```
def pairs(a, b, _l, _c = [], _sum=0):
  if len(_c) == _l:
    if _sum > 2:
      yield _c
  else:
    if a:
      for i in b:
        if a[0]+i+_sum < 8:
          yield from pairs(a[1:], b, _l, _c=_c+[a[0]+i], _sum=_sum+a[0]+i)
        if a[0]+_sum < 8:
          yield from pairs(a[1:], b, _l, _c= _c+[a[0]], _sum=_sum+a[0])

print(list(pairs([1, 2, 3], [-1, 1], 3, _sum=0)))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 4], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 2], [0, 3, 3], [0, 3, 4], [0, 3, 3], [0, 2, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 3], [1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 3], [1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Really appreciate this, it works perfectly. I'm now trying to add additional constraints to this algorithm. If I now have list2 = [-1, 1] for example, I'd like the sum of all elements in the new lists to be between 2 and 8. Unfortunately if a[0]+i+_sum < 8 and a[0]+i+_sum > 2 will output an empty list. I assume because it never passes the if statement. How would you modify the code to cater to this?

Comment: @ValentinC. To specify a "lower bound", I suggest either putting a condition to check for the sum just before the `yield` recursive base case, or filtering the results of the function call to only sublists whose sum is between 2 and 8. Please see my recent edit, as I implemented the former

Comment: How could I have missed that. Thank you so much again for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @ValentinC. No problem, glad to help!

Comment: A follow-up question please. Obviously all solutions to this task will be resource and time intensive, but is recursion the best way to go about a problem like this? I've been taught it's quicker than using loops, for example, but I'm not convinced anymore after some research. Would you have any idea how to 'optimise' this a bit?

Comment: @ValentinC Recursion is really the only way to the best of my knowledge. An iterative solution does certainly exist for a variant of your question, namely, groups of combinations of `list1` and `list2`, where every value from `list2` occurs only once  (or several times in shorter, more reasonable lengths of `list2`), but the result would have little semblance to your actual desired output.

Comment: @ValentinC. As for optimizing, ShadowRanger has the best response, as it is quite impossible to do so with larger input. Granted there are things that could be done to speed up the execution of the program, but only up to a certain input size. The program would still hang after that.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is impossible without *much* stricter constraints (and possibly impossible even then).

Let's look at just *one* group of `list`s. Imagine you're trying the scenario of adding to 15 indices of 30, with all five of your possible values in play. That's 5<sup>15</sup> (over 30 million) ways to fill in the 15 chosen indices, and 30 choose 15 sets of indices to fill in (over 155 million), which combines to 4,733,811,035,156,250,000 (4.7 quintillion) lists. Might be a little less since you'd have the constraint of using each of the five values at least once (otherwise you'd recompute the same `list` with a smaller set of selected values), but it's still going to be insane. And that's just for the 15 index, five values case; the others are going to be somewhat smaller, but most will still be individually impossible to compute in a human lifetime, let alone computable in aggregate.

You could try to filter it down quite a ways by pre-emptively computing the sum of your large input `list`, and skipping any combination of values that's guaranteed to exceed your maximum cumulative value, as well as preemptively reducing the multiplicity of any value that would push you over the cap. But this smells strongly of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040); any time you're considering this level of combinatoric insanity, you probably have a better way to accomplish your task (and/or your task is impossible).

For your simple case, you just combine `itertools` tools to do it:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

def make_lists(list1, list2, limit):
    maxvalues = limit - sum(list1)
    minlist2 = min(list2)
    for numindices in range(1, len(list1)+1):
        if minlist2 * numindices >= maxvalues:
            continue
        for indices in combinations(range(len(list1)), numindices):
            for values in product([x for x in list2 if x < maxvalues], repeat=numindices):
                if sum(values) >= maxvalues:
                    continue
                newlist = list1[:]
                for i, v in zip(indices, values):
                    newlist[i] += v
                yield newlist
```

But that will take "heat death of the universe" time for any meaningful input length. Recursive solutions could filter out invalid outputs more efficiently, but unless the limit is really strict, you're still going to die before the program finishes.

Comment: I completely understand the size of this problem, and thank you for the code above. It is actually very quick but memory intensive, which at the moment would not be a problem. However, I'm having trouble understanding how to include extra constraints in the code. How would I:
1. Apply a minimum sum constraint to the new lists? Say new list sum between 5 and 20.
2. If I extrapolate the above to a ungodly number, is there a way to randomly change only a subset of elements in list1? Let's say half, or a third.